# Testing Load Balancer for Issues

Tags: load, load-balancing, load-testing, haproxy

This is a bit of a broad question.

I am tasked with setting up HAProxy to use as a load balancer for our API servers for our mobile application. How do I verify that it is set up correctly? What are the common pitfalls with switching to a load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first remove the variable of your codebase and test haproxy against nginx or apache serving static files with something simple like apache bench (ab). If that's all working fine, you're probably in good shape for basic functionality. Haproxy can be tricky with urlbegin, urlend and various other path matchers that can match to multiple places.

Once the basic functionality has been figured out, grab the performance test suite for your API (jmeter or whatever you use) and test your throughput and latency against a single instance then against the balanced APIs. Make sure to verify that load is being spread properly.

Some pitfalls -

Sessions: You're using a stateless server and don't rely on session affinity to bind a user's session to the same server, right?

Linux Settings : All of your connections are going through this box, so make sure sysctl settings etc are all well tuned.

NonHttp and Websocket Connections : Be very careful about tuning timeouts and other settings for these.

KeepAlive and HTTP Settings: Do some research on performance tuning of haproxy - there are some important concepts like http server close (these deal with when to close the underlying tcp/ip connections).